# Open all files in directory in vim

Tags: 14.04, vim

To open several files in separate tabs in vim I need to execute command

```
vim -p file1 file2
```

I fave directory that contains many files and I would like to open all files with extension `c` in `vim` editor.

How to make this in short and elegant way?

Comment: Other than `vim -p *.c`? Even then, with `-p` Vim only opens 10 tabs by default.

Answer (score 2):

Default `tabpagemax` is 10 as being pointed out by muru.

you can increase it by setting, for example to 100, to open 100 files max by default

`set tabpagemax=100`

and then use `vim -p *.c` 
Does it have visible performance impact, Need to check

Note: Adding as a answer here as I don't have enough repo to add comment